# is amazon dot fr in responsive or are ther two sites?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

When i access amazon.fr via my mobile it presents a different layout than the one is displayed if I access to amazon.fr via my desktop computer event if i reduce the width of the browser to the size of the mobile.

How does it works?

Actually the url is the same for desktop and mobile sites.

https://www.amazon.fr/

Comment: google responsive vs adaptive, by the sounds of things, that site is adaptive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are absolutely same. But You can not find out the difference by adjusting the browser width.

The changes are made using `window.ready` function (or when window is ready). The styles are applied according to the window size that calculated when loading the page. This is to avoid excess use of `media querying`.

You can find out this difference from your desktop only by **reloading** the page or **clicking on links** in full width and adjusted mobile screen width

Have a look at [here](http://mediumwell.com/responsive-adaptive-mobile/) as well